# How to prevent going back to the login page using the browser's back button after a user log in?

Tags: routes, laravel-8, middleware

To prevent **going back** to the login page using the **browser's back button** I made this **middleware** named '**PreventBackHistory**' and registered it in the karnel.php file.

The **middleware** file:

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PreventBackHistory
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        return $response->header('Cache-Control','nocache,no-store,max-age=0;must-revalidate')
                        ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
                        ->header('Expires','Sun, 02 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    }
}
```

On **karnel**.php -

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'PreventBackHistory' => \App\Http\Middleware\PreventBackHistory::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
```

Then added this middleware on the related **web routes**.

```
Route::prefix('user')->name('user.')->group(function(){
    
        Route::middleware(['guest','PreventBackHistory'])->group(function(){
            Route::view('/login', 'dashboard.user.login')->name('login');
            Route::view('/register', 'dashboard.user.register')->name('register');
    
            Route::post('/create', [UserController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
            Route::post('/check', [UserController::class, 'check'])->name('check');
        });
    
    
        Route::middleware(['auth','PreventBackHistory'])->group(function(){
            Route::view('/home', 'dashboard.user.home')->name('home');
    
            Route::post('/logout', [UserController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
        });
    
    });
```

But I can still **go back** to the **login page** using the back button from the browser after **logging in** and **go back** to **home-page** after **logging out**.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: No, I didn't find the solution. I would suggest upvoting the question to get an answer or if u find an answer please share it.

Answer (score 0):

go to Kernel.php scroll down, try to add your PreventBackHistory middleware in 'web' inside the *protected $middlewareGroups*

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        // Add the preventbackhistory middleware below
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventBackHistory::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```